# How to display gif while application is running?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display *gif* on `PictureBox` which sets `Visible` as a default. And I want to display this when I click on the button; but when i did this it's `Visible` attributes being `Visible == true` after a second and then it *stops running*. I don't understand why ?

```
private void cmdbtnHesapla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pbLoading.Visible = true;
    Application.DoEvents();

    //SomeCode
}
```

Comment: Let `Application.DoEvents();` *rest in peace*; if you want *asynchronous* execution, use `Task`, `await`, `async`

Comment: Your `SomeCode` is blocking the UI thread. Move your working code to a Task or - since this is Winforms - into a BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 0):

1: create 1 forms

2: Drop a picturebox onto your form.

3: Add the .gif file as the image in the picturebox.

4: Show the picturebox when you are loading.

This example may solve your problem: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24044/AJAX-style-Asynchronous-Progress-Dialog-for-WinFor?dung